# fetching data from polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Votes table**:

```
id  user id  vote  votable_id  votable_type 
1      4        5     1           App\Comment
2      2        4     4           App\Answer
....
```

**Answer and comment model**

```
  public function votes()
    {
         return $this->morphOne('App\Vote', 'votable');
    }

   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id'); 
    }
```

**Votes Model**:

```
public function votable()
     {
         return $this->morphTo();
      }
 public function user()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id'); 
     }
```

How do I fetch answers and comments on which logged in user voted from user model.

```
 $user=User::where(['id'=>Auth::user()->id])->with('questions','answers','comments','comments.votes','votes')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to back items from **morphed model** that are exists in **votes model** so you should query morphed model with "votes" relationship **whereHas** condition:

```
$result = Answer::whereHas('votes', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();

$result = Comment::whereHas('votes', function($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
```